# SerialPort.DiscarInBuffer(): should one account for a some time to let the operation finish?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

please bear with me. Serial port handling in C# has always been a painful topic for me, and still, as of today, I'm having some performance issues.

> Is it plausible that the method `DiscardInBuffer()` is partially discarding the reply of `Write()` method?

Consider this prototype function:

```
void Write(string command)
{
    lock(_locker)
    {
        mySerialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
        mySerialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
        mySerialPort.Write(command);
    }
}
```

I use this to write something to the port. Initially, it seemed like a good idea to clear both buffers before writing. However, I (quite often) get incomplete data from the device.

Device communication, in my case, is easy. I send a command and I receive a reply, as a string, and is something like "OK" or "NOT OK". However, the log files of my application state that, sometimes, I get "K" ot "T OK" and alike. It seems that some of the data is lost.

My best guess is that performance improves removing `mySerialPort.DiscardInBuffer();` and using `mySerialPort.ReadExisting();`, which, accidentally, also clears the buffer (tested via PowerShell).

I was thinking that the buffer clearing operation is still in progress when the write operation starts, and, as a consequence, the reply gets, partially, discarded. **Does it make sense?**

What kind of checks can I implement to continue using `mySerialPort.DiscardInBuffer();` in the function, but being confident the thing is not discarding the reply?

Comment: Why do you think it's a good idea to clear the in buffer?

Comment: Because I know that my device is printing out stuff upon external input, for instance when it is connected, and I want to treat that info as noise. If you put that aside, just to make sure that I'm starting from a known start point. Am I going too far, you rekon?

Comment: I'm not sure that it's a good approach, but I don't have extensive experience with serial port communications. Don't the messages from the device have some delimiter, or length-prefix you can do something with?